# zip64 support in php?

Tags: php, zip, unzip

I have a file downloaded by a cron that is in zip64 format.

How can I unzip it using php or via a php cmd()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

surprisingly unix's unzip just worked!

```
exec(unzip -n -q zip-downloaded-by-cron.zip -d photos);
```

Comment: unzip 6.00 has zip64 extensions. Older versions do not.

Answer (score 0):

A couple options that I know of.

If your PHP runs on Windows you can use the COM interface to [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com).

```
$zipInput = "c:\\temp\\zip-downloaded-by-cron.zip"; 
$zip = new COM("Ionic.Zip.ZipFile");
$zip->Initialize($zipInput);
$dirForExtract= "c:\\temp\\extract";
# optional password 
$zip->Password = "AES-Encryption-Is-Secure";
$zip->ExtractAll($dirForExtract);
$zip->Dispose();
```

For DotNetZip, ZIP64 is automatically used when necessary, when reading in a zip file.

Alternatively, you can invoke the command-line tool provided with DotNetZip. 
This has the advantage of working on Linux+Mono, in addition to Windows+.NET. 
The tool is unzip.exe, and you can just invoke (cmd) `unzip.exe downloaded-zip.zip`.  It will automatically handle the zip64 stuff.  There are options on unzip.exe to specify where to extract, which files to extract, and so on.

Comment: Linux no mono, is it possible to use DotNetZip unzip.exe?

Comment: No, if you are on Linux, you need mono to run DotNetZip.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Perl's [`IO::Compress::Zip`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO-Compress-Zlib/) module supports Zip64. If you're comfortable enough to install it you could call a small Perl script via [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Comment: because of the server prob can't install the perl php module. So I can call the script through passthru() or cmd() I need to inflate the zip64 (IO::Uncompress::Unzip ?) I have  perl, v5.8.8 built for i686-linux anyone know a simple perl script i could call?