# working with ZIP files in PHP

Tags: php, file, ftp, zip

I'm creating zip file like this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$fillename = "files.zip";
if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}
```

I'm not sure about it's type, what do it uses, works on 32 or 64 bit, ASCII mode or hexadecimal. I know that the code above creates a zip file file but I don't know which bit(32 or 64). How can I create a zip file(32-bit)?

Comment: ZIP files are pretty straightforward. What do you mean by 32 and 64 bit? Can you clarify what your situation is?

Comment: My question is updated

Comment: Looks like `ZipArchive` might be creating ZIP64 files, it seems to be the common format these days: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#ZIP64 ... Edit: no it doesn't: [zip64 support in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1675535)

Comment: Thank you @Pekka웃 , but I need to create in 32-bit, how can I do that? The server I have to upload for doesn't supports ZIP64.

Comment: As said, ZipArchive doesn't seem to be generating ZIP64 files. Re binary, who is telling you that and why? How is the file being transmitted to the target?

Comment: Using FTP. I'm transferring data using username & password provided by them. It's a property feed

Comment: The issue is then probably going to be with the FTP rather than the way you build the zip

Comment: They sent me this error - "(a) You transfereed the zip in ASCII mode over ftp." Can this be the reason?

Comment: `$fillename = "files.zip";` should be `$filename = "files.zip";`